# How to template a function with const/nonconst pointer/reference arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Let say I have following set of functions:

```
typedef uint8_t byte;

inline byte *as_bytes(char *data) {
    return reinterpret_cast<byte*>(data);
}

inline byte *as_bytes(std::vector<byte> &v) {
    return &v[0];
}

inline byte *as_bytes(QByteArray &a) {
    return as_bytes(a.data());
}

inline const byte *as_cbytes(const char *data) {
    return reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(data);
}

inline const byte *as_cbytes(const std::vector<byte> &v) {
    return &v[0];
}

inline const byte *as_cbytes(const QByteArray &a) {
    return as_cbytes(a.data());
}
```

Question: can I template these functions so that constness and pointer/reference type deduction will work properly? Result that I want to see might look like:

```
template<typename T>
inline byte *as_bytes(T data) {
    return reinterpret_cast<byte*>(data);
}

template<>
inline byte *as_bytes(std::vector<byte> &v) {
    return &v[0];
}

template<>
inline byte *as_bytes(QByteArray &a) {
    return as_bytes(a.data());
}
```

But of course this code won't work for me for 2 reasons:

- I want constness of argument to be deduced and forwarded it to a return type;
- Since we're talking about functions, specialization for `std::vector` and `QByteArray` won't work as expected since always `template<typename T> inline byte *as_bytes(T data)` will be chosen because of function overload.

Maybe there are some C++11/14/17 mechanisms to solve these problems and end up with 3 pretty functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may suit what you want:

```
template<typename T>
inline auto as_bytes(T *data) {
    return reinterpret_cast<
        typename std::conditional<std::is_const<T>{}, const byte*, byte*>::type
    >(data);
}

template <typename T>
inline auto as_bytes(T &t) -> decltype(as_bytes(t.data())) {
    return as_bytes(t.data());
}
```

How does this work:

- the first template function takes a `T*` so that (const) references to `std::vector` / `QByteArray` (or any other types you could add) will never match this template, and the constness is deduce from `T` using a combination of `std::conditional` and `std::is_const`.
- The second template function will match any type `T` that has a member function `data()` (which is the case for `std::vector` (since C++11) and `QByteArray`), and the constness is deduced because `T::data` has a const overload.

Using the trailing return type in the second function will allow you to add extra overload for types that do not provide a `.data()` method without creating ambiguity.